# How do I delete a Windows Azure Shared Cache please?

Tags: caching, azure

I have been forwarded a couple of emails from one of my clients regarding the retirement of Windows Azure Shared Caching.

The emails say ‘Shared caches can be deleted via the Azure Management Portal.’

However, they provide no further instructions, and everything I’ve been able to find on msdn.microsoft.com seems to be out of date as it tells me to go to menu items that are no longer there.

Could anyone please provide up to date instructions on how to delete a Shared cache?

There is only a cache on the Production server, there isn't one on Staging, and the only difference I've been able to find is that the section 'Cache' shows up on Production under Configure, with one listed. That does have an 'X' next to it which appears to delete the cache, however refreshing the page causes it to immediately reappear.

The cache was only added as a work around to try to fix a problem (which it didn't), and isn't actually used, so I just need to delete it, not migrate to a different cache.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

there will be a solution in the new portals shortly (after September 01, 2014) But for now you should still be able to delete in the OLD OLD portal  :-). there's only one config item left and that's exactly that one. https://windows.azure.com/ is the place to be.

sure hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply techmike2kx, but I'm still stuck I'm afraid (I didn't set this up, so trying to work backwards).

I've logged in to the old Azure portal (https://windows.azure.com/)

I've gone to the Caching menu item at the bottom left, and then Services / Caching at the top left, which gives me a list of caches in the middle.

I don't see the Shared cache in the list, only the main cache which was created months earlier and is still in use.